# I can't find msmdpump.dll

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I installed SQL Server 2012 Express Edition 64 bit on Windows 7 64 bit. Installation completed successfully.

But when I try to configure HTTP Access to Analysis Services on Internet Information Services (IIS), I am not able to find `MSMDPUMP.dll` file in `<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<instance>\OLAP\bin\isapi` directory.

Actually OLAP directory doesn't exist on my PC.

Please help me to locate `MSMDPUMP.dll` or tell me whats wrong in my installation.

Thanks.